# pyspark dataframe column name

Tags: string, dataframe, pyspark, multiple-columns

what is limitation for pyspark dataframe column names. I have issue with following code ..

```
%livy.pyspark
df_context_spark.agg({'spatialElementLabel.value': 'count'})
```

It gives ...

```
u'Cannot resolve column name "spatialElementLabel.value" among (lightFixtureID.value, spatialElementLabel.value);'
```

The column name is evidently typed correctly. I got the dataframe by transformation from pandas dataframe. It there any issue with dot in the column name string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dots are used for nested fields inside a structure type.  So if you had a column that was called "address" of type StructType, and inside that you had street1, street2, etc you would access it the individual fields like this:

```
df.select("address.street1", "address.street2", ..)
```

Because of that, if you want to used a dot in your field name you need to quote the field whenever you refer to it.  For example:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

schema = StructType([StructField("my.field", StringType())])

rdd = sc.parallelize([('hello',), ('world',)])
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)

# Using backticks to quote the field name
df.select("`my.field`").show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Finally I decided to rename columns and get rid of dots in column names. I can just confirm your suggestion with backticks works very well.